# no such file or directory error in Makefile with addprefix?

Tags: c, makefile

The addprefix rule in my makefile does not add "src/" in front of my "SRC_FILES" for some reason, I tried to bugged "SRC" using printf and it only show `src/`  and I get the following error :
`error: main.c: No such file or directory`
I don't understand why the addprefix rule doesn't work here. Thanks in advance.

```
SRC_DIR = src/ 

SRC_FILES   = main.c

TEST     = tests/test.c

CFLAGS  += -I $(IDIR) -Wall -Wextra -lm

SRC     = $(addprefix $(SRC_DIR), $(SRC_FILES))

all: $(BIN_NAME)

$(BIN_NAME):
        @cd $(LIB_DIR) ; make re
        @cp $(LIB_DIR)/$(LIB_NAME) ./$(LIB_NAME)
        @printf "debug -> "$(SRC) #trying to debug here.
        @gcc -o $(BIN_NAME) $(SRC) $(LIB_NAME) $(CFLAGS) #get error here.
```

Comment: Do you have a stray/extra whitespace character at the end of `SRC_DIR = src/` ?

Comment: your makefile rules should have dependencies, the problem you have here is you dove into using GNU extensions without first learning the basics of make; I recommend writing a simple portable makefile for something like this. Check this out: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/make.html -- try to rewrite without using anything that's not in that spec, and add GNU exts if you really really need/want them later.

Comment: Set your editor to trim trailing whitespace on save. That will save you another day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The very first thing is you should never add `@` to your recipe lines, or if you really must have them you should never add them until *after* your makefile is already working.  Suppressing this output removes the best debugging tool you have.

If you didn't have the `@` prefix you'd immediately see what the problem is.  As G.M. says, you have extra whitespace at the end of your `SRC_DIR = src/` line.  Make preserves trailing whitespace at the end of lines.

This means that `SRC` contains the string `src/ main.c` instead of `src/main.c`.

The reason your `printf` behaves like this is that you left the variable outside the quotes.  So, the shell command being invoked is:

```
printf "debug -> "src/ main.c
```

which means that the format string passed to printf is `debug -> src/` and `main.c` is the first argument, but your format string doesn't contain any `%s` or anything so it's ignored.  If you'd included the make variable inside the quotes, then you also would have seen the problem:

```
printf "debug -> $(SRC)"
```

would give:

```
printf "debug -> src/ main.c"
```

Then your compile line is this:

```
gcc -o bin src/ main.c ...
```

Again, if you didn't have the `@` prefix, so you could see the commands make invoked, this would be pretty clear.

Comment: Thanks you very much, it was indeed a whitespace at the end i didn't notice with Vim, the reason I use @ is to format my make file output in a pretty way, but I will probably remove them next time I debug a Makefile.

Comment: Don't add them until everything works.  Also, you might consider this instead: http://make.mad-scientist.net/managing-recipe-echoing/